# Could not dequeue a view of kind UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a view controller with two collection views, each one has a cell with a different identifier, but for some reason, I am getting the 'could not dequeue' error.

> 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with >identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or >connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and its causing a runtime error on the AppDelegate. I registered the nibs, based on another stackoverflow question, but it didn't work. Can somebody provide some help?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        if collectionView == collView {
        if defaults.boolForKey("gotPL") {
            let thumbIV = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
            let playTitle = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel

            thumbIV.image = UIImage(data: defaults.arrayForKey("playlistThumbnails")![indexPath.row] as! NSData)
            playTitle.text = defaults.arrayForKey("playlistTitles")![indexPath.row] as? String
            return cell } else { return cell }} else {

            if defaults.boolForKey("gotRecom") {
                let thumbIV = cell2.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImageView
                let videoTitle = cell2.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
                thumbIV.image = UIImage(data: defaults.arrayForKey("recomThumbs")![indexPath.row] as! NSData)
                videoTitle.text = defaults.arrayForKey("recomTitles")![indexPath.row] as? String
                return cell2
            } else { return cell2 }}
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I think the error has to do with the fact that you're dequeuing two different cells from a single collection view that has one cell registered to it (i.e. CollectionView A has Cell A, CollectionViewB has Cell B). I recommend you first check the collection view that is being passed (from the method argument) and dequeue the appropriate registered cell. I can explain that in more detail if you'd like. Can you post the error log?

Comment: Thanks! Excuse my ignorance. Is the error log what is printed on the console when I get the runtime crash?

Comment: No worries, and yup, exactly that!

Comment: *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UICollectionView.m:3690
2016-01-24 21:01:33.965. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind:UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard' You can find the rest here: http://jkoenigswift.blogspot.com/2016/01/uicollectionview-error.html

Comment: I'm super confident it's because you're calling dequeue twice on the same collectionView where it only has one cell registered to it. I posted and explained more here: https://gist.github.com/ajfigueroa/502ed023984e6c7c79cb

I hope it helps!

Comment: You might be right. What I ended up doing was having the same identifier "Cell" for both collections (customized differently for each). Somehow that fixed it!

Comment: No worries, happy coding!